# ChartLegends and BarChart Ignores ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, legending, charts

In version 11.0.1 it appears that `ColorFunction` is being ignored for `BarChart` with grouped data.

With

```
dat = <|0 -> <|2007 -> 7, 2008 -> 8, 2009 -> 9, 2010 -> 10|>, 
        1 -> <|2007 -> 5, 2008 -> 6, 2009 -> 7, 2010 -> 8|>|>;
```

Then

```
BarChart[dat,
 ChartLabels -> {Automatic, None},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All of the *2010* entries are not the same colour and the colours in the legend are not using the colours of `ColorFunction`.  Similarly for the other groups.

This seems like a bug. Any ideas for workarounds?
Win 7 Pro

Confirmed bug: Have to figure out the case number as I am getting a couple of confirms at the moment but all on the same case number. It is one of these but three where responded with separate emails all from one case number so I can't tell which one it is. [CASE:3780234] [CASE:3780235] [CASE:3780239]

Comment: a workaround: `ChartStyle->"DeepSeaColors"` instead of `ColorFunction`?

Comment: @kglr  I need `ColorData` as I am actually using `ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}]`. I took that part out to make the question minimal.

Comment: It does seem like a bug, but isn't the coloring in general wrong here?  None of the colors for the different years match each other.  If you take out the `ColorFunction` option, then the bars for the years are the same color.

Comment: @JasonB Yes. I mention that in the question.

Comment: @Edmund, sorry - I didn't read fully and thought your only issue was with the legend colors

Comment: This still occurs in v11.3 Perhaps someone should file a bug?

Comment: Seems stil a bug in 11.3 , also with PieChart. It has to do wtih ChartLegends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind a crude hack:

```
Unprotect[ColorData]; 
ColorData["x"] = ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}];

BarChart[dat, ChartLabels -> {Automatic, None}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 ChartStyle -> "x"]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting workaround. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

This example is a bit tricky, since you don't actually *want* to use a `ColorFunction`, since then the bars are colored by their height and you don't have a consistent coloring by keys.

So the bar chart in the OP looks correct based on the input, but the legend is obviously nonsense - that should be reported as a bug.  Perhaps if a `ColorFunction` is used, the `ChartLegend` should default to a color bar like `DensityPlot` gives.

Simon gives a good workaround that uses the `ChartStyle -> <named_color_scheme>` option method, but as he says it is a bit of a hack (not that I don't love a good hack).  This is a convenience method that makes it so you don't have to give explicit styles for each element.  But the in this case the OP wants to customize it a bit, having the colors go in reverse order, so we can just use the more basic functionality of `ChartStyle` and give it a list of `Style` specifications.

```
colors = ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}] /@ Subdivide[3];
BarChart[dat, ChartLabels -> {Automatic, None}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 ChartStyle -> colors]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is the magic sauce!  Exactly what I am looking for and without the hacks.  +1 while we wait for challengers.  It also appears that I may have misinterpreted the use of `ColorFunction` in this instance.  Perhaps compounded by the odd legend.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a color function of your choice as the setting for `Method` suboption `"ChartDefaultStyle"`:

```
BarChart[dat,
  ChartLabels -> {Automatic, None},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ChartLegends -> Automatic,
  Method -> {"ChartDefaultStyle" -> (ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"} , #] &)}]
```

[image]

With

```
dat2 = AssociationThread[Range[0, 5] -> 
 Table[AssociationThread[Range[2000, 2008] -> RandomInteger[9, 9]], 6]]
```

we get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ChartLegend bug also with PieChart

I give another solution:

I use other data for simplicity, answer is already accepted and I post because I think it can be a simpler approach using `Legended[]`

```
Legended[

 PieChart[{mix, males, females},
  ColorFunction -> (Switch[#, mix, LightGreen, males, LightBlue, 
      females, LightPink] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  (*,ChartLegends\[Rule]{"mixed gender","male gender",
  "female gender"} BUG*)
  ]
 ,
 PointLegend[{LightGreen, LightBlue, LightPink},
  {"Mix", "Male", "Female"}
  ]
 ]
```